# Angular: observable-based multi filtering

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have the following input:

```
<form *ngIf="tests.length">
    <md-form-field class="whitePlaceholder" floatPlaceholder="never">
      <input mdInput placeholder="Find Tests..." [formControl]="testCtrl"
      class="whitePlaceholder">
    </md-form-field>
  </form>
```

The input is responsible for filtering tests by name within a list:

```
<md-list-item *ngFor="let test of filteredTests | async">
</md-list-item>
```

I run the following code when I finish loading the tests from my API:

```
this.filteredTests = this.testCtrl.valueChanges
        .startWith(null)
        .debounceTime(250)
        .map(name => name ? this.filterTests(name) : tests.slice());
```

It works great, but now I added another filter: the user can select an option from a radio button. This is the method responsible for filtering by the checked button:

```
updateList($event) {
    if ($event.value === 'all') {
      this.filteredTests = Observable.of(this.tests);
    } else {
      this.filteredTests = this.filteredTests
        .map((test) => test ? this.filterTestsStatus($event.value) : this.filteredTests.slice());
    }
  }
```

**The problem:** When user clicks a radio button to filter by one of the options, the `filteredTests` variable is overwritten and the test name search input mentioned above stops working.

**Question**: How I can make my app work with my name filter and my radio options filter instead of overwriting my `filteredTests`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these lines actually correct?

```
this.filteredTests = this.filteredTests
    .map((test) => test ? this.filterTestsStatus($event.value) : this.filteredTests.slice());
```

IDK why you are not using TypeScript here, as it would help a lot, but I don't think types match here.

So say `this.filteredTests` is of a type `Observable<TestType>`. Then map takes a function from `TestType` to `TestType`, but what you pass is `TestType` to `Observable<TestType>` as `this.filteredTests.slice()` is clearly an `Observable`.

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, as you seem to be mapping falsy `tests` to `Observables` of `tests`. And what do you expect `slice()` to do here?